# tikz must be imported after gb4e?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gb4e

I am using the `gb4e` and `tikz` packages. It seems that as long as I import `gb4e` before `tikz`, I will get an error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. \catcode`\noexpand\^^A

However, if I import `gb4e` after `tikz`, there will be no problem. Why is this the case?

Here is a minimal working example reproducing the error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

link for `gb4e`: https://ctan.org/pkg/gb4e?lang=en

Comment: The very first sentence of the `gb4e` manual says "The le gb4e.sty1 allows `_` (subscript) and `^` (superscript) to be used in
ordinary text, which is handy, but because it changes their denitions it
must be loaded after any le that uses them in their TEX meaning." This strongly suggests that the answer to your question title "tikz must be imported after gb4e?"  is "No, you need to load `gb4e` last.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be happy to delete this, but the manual of `gb4e` starts with the sentence

> The le gb4e.sty allows `_` (subscript) and `^` (superscript) to be used
>   in ordinary text, which is handy, but because it changes their
>   definitions it must be loaded after any le that uses them in their TEX
>   meaning.

[image]

So, if you want have the ability to use `_` and `^` in ordinary text, you need to load `gb4e` last, well, because the it changes the definitions of `_` and `^`.

**HOWEVER** it turns out that does not really lead to a super stable solution. Let's try to make `gb4e` happy and load it last. The following works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
test 
% \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{2^3}\myx % <-does not work
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{pow(2,3)}\myx
\end{document}
```

Yet if you parse any expression with `^` in it with pgf, *this will not work*:

```
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{2^3}
```

You can avoid this by switching of the ability to use `_` and `^` in ordinary text with `\noautomath`. Then you can also load Ti*k*Z last.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
test 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{2^3}\myx % works now
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{pow(2,3)}\myx
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks. That makes a lot of sense! So I need to know what package is using `_` and `^` then. :)

Comment: @Hai Unfortunately the story is more complicated. Yes, loading `tikz` works. Using it will only be possible with limitations. Maybe there are alternatives that are safer to use? Anyway, I extended the answer to mention some of the possible pitfalls. (Also +1 to your question because now I see that one may want to warn users of these issues. Whether or not `expl3`/`sparse` works in full glory works at all I do not know but I would not at all be surprised if it doesn't. Simple things seem to work.)

Comment: Ah, then it seems that all `_` and `^` are considered to be the sub/super scripts literals at all times? There is one alternative package `linguex` that also make linguistics examples: https://ctan.org/pkg/linguex?lang=en. Linguists especially syntacticians need a lot of trees (tikz) and examples (gb4e/linguex). So I think someone must have encountered such issues before...

Comment: @Hai Yes, I just found the command `\noautomath` which allows you to avoid this. I added this to the answer.

Comment: @Hai This is a well known issue with `gb4e`. The use of `_` and `^` in text is also useful for linguists, but can sometimes interfere with others. So just use `\noautomath` to turn it off. If you do so immediately after loading the package, then loading order shouldn't matter.